# Please help Txhash

Tags: address

i looked up my txhash on etherscan and the (from) address does not match my own. I verified the (To) address and it is correct. Even the value is the same as my purchase. How is this possible? What are my options? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it's not your own? Transactions don't have a 'from' address, it's possible etherscan made a mistake in guessing who it's from. But more likely it is one of your addresses, perhaps a different one to the one you thought, such as a change address. Or if you're using an exchange or web wallet, it might just be from another one of the UTXOs that exchange/wallet has, not deposited to you